# which sensor i have to use to find out distance of a particular device using sensors in iot

Tags: sensors, iot

I want to create a device like tracker to find objects like keys or any important things. I want to add that sensor to that valuable thing to find where the object i left. I can't use motion sensor, ultrasonic sensor or air proximity because of its check distance form one direction. I need to find out the distance of the object from any direction.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using one of both:

- GPS
- RDF (Radio Direction Find)

The first is great if you have open sky and client (the looking device) is able to navigate through GPS (thinking in a smartphone).

The second is good for indoor but it can be hard to program and find parts. Look to [soloshot](http://www.soloshot.com). It follows a beacon attached to person of interest. I don´t have their spec but this is a kind of RDF I bet. Airplanes use a avionic based on RDF idea. Read the wikpeadia [article on RDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_direction_finder).

Others may come up with other ideas, those where the first that popped in my mind.